# Can multiple files be stored in the same block?

Tags: c, file, filesystems

I am coding some block level operations, and I want to make sure I don't bash over other files. On an ext2/3/4 file system, can multiple files be stored in the same block? My first instinct is to say no way, but I wanted to check with the community.

Comment: some filesystems have the capability to split a block up into smaller sub-blocks (I specifically remember being taught about BSD's FFS having this capability, back in basic OS courses in Uni). No idea about the ext* filesystems specifically, though.

Comment: the ext* file systems, used on *inx OS's allocate a full block (usually 4096 usable bytes) even if they only need 1 byte of the new block.  so, the simple answer is NO.  I.E. only one file can be kept on a block of the disk.  (however, you might want to look at archiving, as that just separates a series of programs via a header, therefore allowing the possibility of having more than one program per block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is difficult to answer. Maybe the correct answer might be in theory yes, but in practice no.

## ext2 / ext3

Speaking ext2 and ext3, superblock and inode structures were designed to allow blocks to be fragmented.  (see: `fs/ext2/ext2.h` and `fs/ext3/ext3.h`)

short snippet of `fs/ext3/ext3.h` given here:

```
struct ext3_super_block {
/*00*/  __le32  s_inodes_count;     /* Inodes count */
    __le32  s_blocks_count;     /* Blocks count */
    __le32  s_r_blocks_count;   /* Reserved blocks count */
    __le32  s_free_blocks_count;    /* Free blocks count */
/*10*/  __le32  s_free_inodes_count;    /* Free inodes count */
    __le32  s_first_data_block; /* First Data Block */
    __le32  s_log_block_size;   /* Block size */
    __le32  s_log_frag_size;    /* Fragment size */

// ...

struct ext3_inode {
    __le16  i_mode;     /* File mode */
    __le16  i_uid;      /* Low 16 bits of Owner Uid */

// ...
    __le32  i_faddr;    /* Fragment address */
```

Although prepared for, at least in the linux kernel (up to version 3.13)  block fragmentation was never implemented, forcing fragment size to be equal to block size. (see: `fs/ext3/super.c`)

```
if (blocksize != sbi->s_frag_size) {
    ext3_msg(sb, KERN_ERR,
           "error: fragsize %lu != blocksize %u (unsupported)",
           sbi->s_frag_size, blocksize);
    goto failed_mount;
}
```

Afaik GNU/Hurd doesn't implement block fragmentation of ext2/3 filesystems as well. Most probably there will be no OS around, that implements it.

Nevertheless, checking `s_log_frag_size` in the superblock before starting your block level operations might not be a bad idea, as you will be on the safe side.

## ext4

With ext4 the wohle story becomes less troublesome, as ext4 doesn't allow block fragmentation any more. The superblock field used to store fragment size has been given a new job, and the iode field used to store the fragment address (renamed to `i_obso_faddr`) has been marked as obsolete in the sources.

```
struct ext4_inode {
    __le16  i_mode;     /* File mode */
    __le16  i_uid;      /* Low 16 bits of Owner Uid */
// ...
    __le32  i_obso_faddr;   /* Obsoleted fragment address */
```